# OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow - exchange authorization code on Frontend VS Backend?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

i am developing an application with Angular Frontend and Java/Spring-Backend. For logging into our backend we are using **Oauth2 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE** and **Open ID Connect**.

When the user navigates to a protected route he is redirected to his IDP and has to login. After that he is returned to a redirect_uri with the authorization_code as URL parameter. So far everything is clear.

Now I am not sure what the best way to exchange this code for the access_token is? So far I've done this on the client (in JavaScript) and used the received JWT for further backend calls (on the backend I just verify the signature) and that does seem to work. But in other projects I've seen that colleagues actually used the backend kind of like a proxy. So they send the authorization_code to the Java-backend and the backend does the exchange.

Now I've read a lot, but can't seem to grasp the full implications of that. It does seem to me that it's safer to have the client/frontend do this. But on the other hand the backend is actually trusted, so we could actually use a client_secret in this case.

The question now is: Are both cases considered safe? Or is one considered more secure and if so: why?

Thanks in advance

***Edit**: Just to clarify - we don't really need to access another resource server, the use case is that we just want to be safely authenticated **to our own backend** - once authenticated we switch to a session cookie anyway, so we don't store the access_token anywhere at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the tokens in the backend is always a more secure approach because it reduces the attack surface and makes the code in the client much simpler.

A good starting point is to take a look at this BCP

- [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-07) (section 6.2)

Another reference is:

- [Cheat Sheet: OAuth for Browser-Based Applications (e.g. a JavaScript SPA)](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Cheat-Sheet-OAuth-for-Browser-Based-Applications)

To make your JavaScript simple, I would do all the client authentication in the backend and when the backend gets the token, then create the session with your client. In that way the JavaScript client does not need to touch any tokens. Your internal resources/API would be accessed through the service that is responsible for the session. Clean and simple! :-)

yes! I think the classic mistake is to let JavaScript touch your tokens. You will sleep much better at night knowing that the tokens are only handled in the backend. Also, less security complexity and things you must master and understand! **We must fight complexity!**

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and the link. Was a good reed, but doesn't seem to FULLY cover our case, since the case assumes that we want to talk to a resource server. That's not really the case. Actually we really want to use this to authenticate to our own backend and switch to a regular session once authenticated, so we don't need to store the access_token at all (since we don't need it after the login anymore) - I will update my question to clarify this

Comment: updated my answer, simply shield the browser client from the tokens!

Comment: I now read a bit more. I guess what we are really doing is 6.3 - our backend IS the resource server in this case! I really should stop seeing our application as a single package, when nowadays there is a clear distinction between our frontend and the backend.
6.3 seems to match our use-case 100% and that does give me confidence that the way I am using is fine - or maybe I missed something?

Comment: Oh, thanks for your update. Didn't think about that. While we are not STORING the access_token right now  the client still has to handle the access_token at least once - maybe that's what makes the 2nd choice better? Oh man, my head is smoking already :)

Comment: added paragraph at the end of my answer, does that make the answer acceptable?

Comment: Also see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeRALmfyoqg&ab_channel=NDCConferences

Answer (score 3):

The actual authorization code can only be used once so it doesn't matter if it is sent from front end or back end.

There are two common models here:

**OPTION 1: WEB BACK END / PROXY PATTERN**

This is used if you want to keep tokens out of the browser and use HTTP only cookies as a back end credential instead:

- Web back end issues a same domain HTTP only cookie and stores tokens in either a database or the cookie itself
- Web UI makes all API calls by first calling the web back end with the cookie
- Web back end then looks up tokens and forwards them to the API
- You need to deal with web threats such as CSRF and XSS

Challenges are:

- More complexity than you'd like
- Some architecture limitations

**OPTION 2: SPA PATTERN**

This is the cross domain model you are using and is technically simpler up to a point::

- Web UI makes API calls by sending an access token
- You need to deal with threats such as XSS and focus in particular on ensuring that use of tokens in the browser is no less secure than use of cookies
- You need to store tokens in a secure manner in the browser, such as in memory

Challenges are:

- If you have gaps in your security they will be easier to exploit since users can more easily see their own tokens
- Token renewal and cross tab navigation aspects are trickier in this model.

**FACTORS**

These are the main factors when making a choice:

- Security threat model - tokens v cookies and other factors
- Wider architecture goals for Web UIs
- Perception of stakeholders is often the single biggest consideration

Whatever you decide I would recommend starting with requirements rather than a particular technology stack.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

I prefer option 2 since I think the architectural options are far better, but it requires care. The following links hopefully help you understand how I reasoned out my preferred solution:

- [Web Architecture Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-spas/)
- [Threat Model - Cookies v Tokens](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/08/ui-token-management)
- [End State and Cloud Deployment](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/spa-reverse-proxy-based-token-renewal/)

Not everyone agrees with me though. Sometimes in software there are multiple solutions. What is important is that security threats are covered. You can potentially do that with either solution.

Answer (score 0):

When your are called token from your client it's not the authorization flow it's implicit flow, and it's could be used when you don't have backend, and when you have backend you always should use authorization code flow as you've mentioned. You can learn more about openid flows [here.](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660)

Authorization code flow is considering more secured because it use backchannel communication(server to server) with idp for receiving tokens, while implicit flow send request from browser.

Comment: we are not using implicit flow, that one would basically do "both in one" (e.g. a single step for retrieving the access_token instead of using two separate steps).

Comment: You can run authorization flow 100% in the browser if you want to. But I wouldn't recomend it.

Answer (score 0):

Sending client calls with PKCE is new technology and it's considered as safe but definitely authorization code flow is better choice for backend.

Comment: PKCE is only applicable for the authorization code flow. and PKCE is a must today to avoid security issues.